# Parsing a PDB file to find frequency of atoms per amino acid

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm trying to parse a PDB file with just the lines that start with ATOM. I want my output to look like:

```
amino acid  C     N     S     O
ARG         0.03  0.08  0.00  0.03
ASN         0.05  0.10  0.00  0.09
ASP         0.05  0.04  0.00  0.12
…etc
total:      531   142   9     156
```

So far, my code gives me a string with just the amino acids and the atom associated with it.

```
import re
with open('3bmp.pdb') as pdb:
     for line in pdb:
          if line[:4] == 'ATOM':
               new = line.strip()
               for aa in new:
                    aa = new[17:21]
                    for atom in new:
                         atom = new[77]
pdb.close()
```

Comment: Why loop over `aa in new` then reassign? `aa = new[17:21]`? And surely you want to split the lines, not strip?

Comment: In a pdb file, you cannot split. aa extracts the 3-letter code amino acid and atom extracts the one-letter atom

Comment: Are you able to show the file? But still, I don't think `aa = new[17:21]` after `for aa in new` does what you want... Possibly you want `for aa in new[17:21]`? Same for `atom = new[77]`